# Parent activity view returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, null, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottomNavView and when I try to access the parent activity view by using requireActivity().findViewById() in the default/first fragment, it returns null and crashes.

But it works on other fragments of the bottonnavview. Only the initial fragment shows this behaviour. Any Idea?

first fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentCallregBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
    progress = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_circle)
}
```

main activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding.root)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    navView = binding.navView
    progress = binding.progressCircle

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_home)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/daynight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_home"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/french_blue"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment layout is empty for now

mobile_navigation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
     <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
      android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation" 
      app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_callreg">
  
     <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/navigation_callreg" 
         android:name="neo.starcool.app.ui.fragments.CallRegFragment" 
         android:label="@string/title_home" 
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_callreg" /> 
  
     <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/navigation_open" 
         android:name="neo.starcool.app.ui.fragments.OpenCallFragment" 
         android:label="@string/title_home" 
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_closed" /> 
  
     <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/navigation_pending" 
         android:name="neo.starcool.app.ui.fragments.PendingFragment" 
         android:label="@string/title_dashboard" 
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_opencall" /> 
  
     <fragment 
         android:id="@+id/navigation_closed" 
         android:name="neo.starcool.app.ui.fragments.ClosedFragment" 
         android:label="@string/title_notifications" 
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pending" /> 
 </navigation>
```

Comment: Can you show some codes on what you do in default/first fragment?

Comment: How about your ```Activity``` that sets up all of these ```Fragment```? BTW, you can edit your question and post the code in your question instead of providing us a link for easier trace. Thanks!

Comment: please post your layout xml also

Comment: Can you also show ```mobile_navigation.xml```?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error it very wired one.

Base on what you gave

> This below will alway return null also that's not a the best pratice by access like that

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   progress = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_circle)
}
```

Quick think by it , If you call the same line in another action . Example:

```
textView.setOnClickListener {
         progress = requireActivity().findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_circle)// bad

   progress =  (requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_circle) // better
}
```

> That will never be null either crash

However if you want to access to activity (parent class) it better done with **Method / Funtion**

Example:

```
**Activity**      
fun hindProgressBar() {
   binding.progressCircle.visibility = View.GONE
}


**Fragment**
(requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.hindProgressBar()
```

Why we have to use null safety casting:

```
(requireActivity() as? MainActivity)
```

That's way where we can tell code who is their parent. If a fragment being use by multi activity it does help your navigate to which and where it belong and how you want it to.

Comment: This did not sove the issue. (requireActivity() as? MainActivity) still has 'requireActivity()'

Comment: Yes it obviously still have and will be have. Since fragments attached to it.

Comment: By casting it it prevents from crash. If you use a fragment in different activities it comes in handy.